# What C++ function should return?

Tags: c++, time-t

I have the following snippet of code:

```
 time_t data1 = time(0)+86400; 
 struct tm * data_emprestimo = localtime( & data1 );
 cout << "Hoje: " << data_emprestimo->tm_mday << '/' << (data_emprestimo->tm_mon + 1) << '/' << (data_emprestimo->tm_year + 1900) << endl;
```

It works well.

But I wonder what kind I should return in a function to get what cout echos and put on a variable: struct tm? Just tm? Array? String?

I've tried something like this:

```
struct tm retornaData(int segundosAdd);
            ...
            ...
struct tm retornaData(int segundosAdd){
   return data_emprestimo;
}
```

but it did not work.

And I already googled that a lot!

Comment: You want to get `data_emprestimo->tm_mday` ?

Comment: I want this return format -> '2012-12-17'

Comment: You should really translate that to english. It's less readable now.

Comment: returning `struct something` is C-oriented, C++ isn’t quite the same. You should first get learned C++ ;)

Comment: skp, do you read my question? "I am a beginner with C++..."

Comment: @Eric - In C++ it is almost always unnecessary to say `struct tm` because the compiler already knows that `tm` is a struct. In the C language the rules are a bit different.

Comment: Yep, @BoPersson! Now, I get the point! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct tm * data_emprestimo
```

declares a pointer to a struct, so to return the struct itself as a value, you need to dereference the pointer, `return *data_emprestimo;`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you wish to write a function that returns a string representation of a date.

Within c++ std::string would be the natural return type for string data.
A more C-style approach might suggest you pass in a char * as a the buffer to which you wish the date printed - in general std::string is seen to be a cleaner and more robust approach.